# What is a person (not a company) who provides a service called?

Tags: word-choice, single-word-requests, terminology

I need the correct English word for someone who provides a service.

The word "service provider" seems obvious but it is not correct. According to the [Cambridge Dictionary](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/british/service-provider), a *service provider* should be defined as an ISP. According to [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Service_provider), a *service provider* is not a person but a company.

There should be a word for a person who provides a service (such as cleaning your house, fixing your car, teaching you a new language, taking care of your pets, etc.) which is the context where I need this word. A sample sentence:

> If two persons (working for the same company) provide a service for me at home, then there are two ______.

Comment: Very similar, if not a duplicate: [Word for one-person business](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/10841/what-is-a-one-person-business-called)

Comment: Thank you but that is not what I mean. A person who provides a service can be part of a large company and not run a one-person business at all. I need a general term for someone who provides a service.

Comment: Generally, you'd use a word specific to the service: *masseuse*, *sculptor*, *coach*, *groundskeeper*, etc. Otherwise, the generic term would be whatever business relationship you have: *contractors*, *vendors*, *aides*, etc.

Comment: Based on your criteria, about the only term that fits is "worker".

Comment: @choster make that an answer please the question as posted doesn't really work... So none of the answers do either.  You can fix that.

Comment: The fact that "Service Provider" has become shorthand for "Internet Service Provider" (ISP) in the internet context shouldn't take away from the general meaning of the words, despite what many (maybe most) of the internet-centric dictionaries say. If your audience can't determine from your own context that you are not describing something else, you need to provide better context, that's all.

Comment: My son receives counseling at school from the social worker.  She is his "service provider."  In this context, that is the standard terminology.  When I had an injury, and needed help with bathing, a caregiver came to my home.  I could call her, specifically, a *caregiver*, but I could also use a more generic term and call her a "service provider" or "provider."  We call our doctors our "medical providers."

Comment: I think the thing to take out of the answers and comments is that the phrasing "service provider" is must suitable and offers a good description of the "contract" between you and that person.

Answer (score 3):

The correct word for someone who provides a service is [**servitor**](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/servitor), although this is a bit archaic in usage and usually they would be referred to according to exactly what service they were providing.

Answer (score 2):

It's still called a company, even if it's only one person.

If you want a more specific word, try "sole proprietorship".

Comment: If two persons (working for the same company) provide a service for me at home, then there are two ????? . I do not think two sole proprietorships, because there is no one man company involved.

Answer (score 2):

If you employ a person and pay them a regular wage or salary, they are an *employee*.

If you negotiate a contract with an individual to provide a service, with that person billing you for services rendered, that person is a *contractor*.

If you hire a company to provide you services, the people working for that company are *employees* (or sometimes *contractors*) of that company and *contractors* from your viewpoint.

The general term for any of the above is "worker".

Answer (score 1):

In general, a person who provides a professional service is called a *consultant*.

Comment: Disagree with "in general". A consultant provides a very specific kind of professional service. If that service is house-cleaning, car maintenance or teaching, to use the OP's examples, they would not normally be described as a consultant.

Comment: I would not consider house-cleaning or car maintenance as professional services: *Professional services are occupations in the tertiary sector of the economy requiring special training in the arts or sciences. Some professional services require holding professional licenses such as architects, auditors, engineers, doctors and lawyers.*

Comment: I think a lot of self-employed carpenters would take offense at being called "consultants".

Comment: I don't know why one would call a carpenter a consultant.  Carpentry is not a professional service.  It is in the field of construction.  The distinction can be made between what are referred to as *blue collar* (carpentry) and *white collar* (legal, medical) professions.  An independent  worker in the latter may be called a consultant, but likely not so with the former.

Comment: That's the highfalutin word for a *handyman*. Just the same as with *engineering consultants* who practice the custodial arts: janitors.

Answer (score 1):

The word that you are looking for is [supplier](http://www.aamboli.com/translate/supplier) which is defined as:

> someone whose business is to supply a particular service or commodity

So in this case it would be service.
In fact you could also use simply [provider](http://www.aamboli.com/translate/provider), which in fact is a synonym of supplier.

Answer (score 0):

I guess a generic "service person" should be ok - though often at times  you will find term being used for armed forces personnel.

Answer (score 0):

I would use *businessperson* (or *businessman/businesswoman*) for this.

> **businessperson** (*noun*)
> A man or woman who works in commerce, especially at an executive level
>
> <sub>[Oxford](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/american_english/business-person?q=businessperson)</sub>

The last part of the definition makes this word questionable for the context, but this is a very general word. It could describe anything from a babysitter to a CEO.

Comment: The kind of services I mean, are services that are not performed by people at an executive level.

Comment: _Businessperson_ doesn't have to describe an executive. If you're a janitor, you're conducting the business of cleaning. It's a little bit of a stretch, but in my opinion it works.

Comment: I still have an issue because of the definition in the oxford dictionary. I really mean people who are especially not (!) at an executive level and do not have a high position at all. I can not simply ignore "especially at an executive level". I consider this as a hint for not using this term.

Answer (score 0):

The additional word required for your Google search is *industry* or *sector* ([service industry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:Service_industries), [tertiary sector](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tertiary_sector_of_the_economy) –Wiki) but I think you're after the word *ancillary*. If I may rephrase your comment:

The people who provide services within, and that are part of, a larger company are called **ancillary** staff/personnel.

> providing necessary support to the primary activities or operation of an organization, institution, industry, or system. –Google

Answer (score 0):

You might consider, ***caregiver***

> A person who gives help and protection to someone (such as a child, an old person, or someone who is sick)
>
> [Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/caregiver)
>
> **Are You Paying Your Caregiver Minimum Wage?**
>
> *Yes, you love your nanny, your housekeeper, your pet sitter and the other caregivers in your life. But do you pay them a fair wage?*
>
> [care.com](http://www.care.com/hiring-cleaning-help-p1387-q30830725.html)
>
> **Professional Caregivers**
>
> *We only hire professional caregivers who have chosen caregiving as their life’s work.  As simple as this may seem, it makes a huge difference.  How confident would you be if the mechanic fixing your car had never fixed a car before?  How would you feel if you knew that your hair dresser just got out of cosmetology school last week?  We understand that providing you a skilled and experienced caregiver is essential to fulfilling the WRAPAROUND promise.*
>
> [All For Your Home Care](http://allforyouhomecare.com/wraparound/)

Also, ***caretaker***

> One that gives physical or emotional care and support : *served as caretaker to the younger children*
>
> [Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/caregiver)

Answer (score 0):

A 'Producer'? someone who provides a good/s or service/s.
A good can be : A phone, or anything that's touchable you own.
A service can be : Like a cleaner or babysitter but government provides services like public schools and the police.

Comment: Hello, Cameron. Have you a dictionary definition matching this claimed sense of 'producer'? (If this _is_ from a dictionary, it needs attributing.)

Answer (score 0):

How about: *workman*?

[OED](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/workman)

> [with adj.] a person with a specified skill in a job or craft

If you use an adjective with *workman*, it works out just fine. e.g., "... like all good workmen."

Answer (score -1):

The can be called *vendors* – vendors provides goods or services

Comment: Hello, Dayo. This is apparently true, but you need to add dictionary support. Then perhaps the down-voter will retract their vote.

Comment: As defined [here](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/vendor), [here](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/vendor), and [here](http://whatis.techtarget.com/definition/vendor), a vendor can be either a person or a company.  Also, this term is generally used to refer to a seller of products (goods), and only rarely a provider of services.

Answer (score -2):

Try "sole trader". Bit too formal for some examples like teaching a language or looking after pets but I think that's where their specific terms come into play (tutor, babysitter).

You can just modify "service provider" with "sole" at the front and it specifies the nature of the single person.